# Array index out of bounds exception in java code

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing the code to print a matrix on taking user input in the form of n value:
Suppose if,
n= 3
output:
3 3 3
3 0 3
3 1 3
3 2 3
3 3 3

I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException in the line: `a[i][j]=n;`

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         //System.out.println("Enter n");
         int n = scan.nextInt();
         System.out.println(n);
         int a[][]= new int[n][n];
         int b=0;
         int mid = n/2 +1;
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
             {
                 if(i+j==mid)
                 {
                     a[i][j]=n-b;
                     b++;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    a[i][j]=n;
                 }


             }
         }
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
             {
                 System.out.print(a[i][j]);
             }
             System.out.println();
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with the code that you are using.

Comment: `for(int j=0;i<n;j++)` no stop condition for your second loop, this is an infinite loop

Comment: @Hearner I just changed that, still it shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If a request for a negative or an index greater than or equal to size of array is made, then the JAVA throws a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception. This is unlike C/C++ where no index of bound check is done. TheArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is aRuntime Exception thrown only at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

minor correction in a loop

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         //System.out.println("Enter n");
         int n = scan.nextInt();
         System.out.println(n);
         int a[][]= new int[n][n];
         int b=0;
         int mid = n/2 +1;
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<n;j++) //minor correction here
             {
                 if(i+j==mid)
                 {
                     a[i][j]=n-b;
                     b++;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    a[i][j]=n;
                 }


             }
         }
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
             {
                 System.out.print(a[i][j]);
             }
             System.out.println();
         }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
for(int j=0;i<n;j++)
```

you increment while "i < n" but you increment "j++".
When your j reaches value 3, the inner loop continues, but exceeds the array-length (of 3, because the hightest array-index is actually 2).

(Also on a minor sidenote, it is usually preferrable to write ++i or ++j within for-loop increments. This is not a rule, just easier to read for most oldscool c-Devs). Also consider leaving spaces to inprove readability:

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    // System.out.println("Enter n");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(n);
    int a[][] = new int[n][n];
    int b = 0;
    int mid = n / 2 + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i + j == mid) {
                a[i][j] = n - b;
                b++;
            } else {
                a[i][j] = n;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```